# How to set line length in centimeters and draw such a line (C# in WPF on Canvas)?

Tags: c#

I do this, I programmatically get the dpi value (along the OX axis and along the OY axis is 144), I convert it to points (virt. pixels) per centimeter (equal to 56.69 points / cm),
from a given length in centimeters (for example, 10 cm) I turn into a length in points (equal to 566.93),
I draw this line on Canvas - as a result, the length of this line (in cm) is 30 percent (measured with a regular ruler) more than the originally specified length in cm. This does not suit!
The screen scale is set to 150%. Display resolution 1920*1080.
I define the dpi value (dots per inch) as follows

```
PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
double dpiX = -1, dpiY = -1;
if (source != null)
{
dpiX = 96.0 * source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;
dpiY = 96.0 * source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22;
}
```

Please, who faced it, prompt links, sources, the solution.

Comment: _"The screen scale is set to 150%"_ - Set it to 100% or account for it.